# What is the most efficient way to parse a string of integers to an array?

Tags: solidity, oracles, string

I perform an Oraclize query on an XML file, and receive this string in return:

```
["31", "25", "24"]
```

What would be the most efficient way to parse through this string and store the numbers into a `uint8` array using the minimum amount of gas?


Or is there a better way to go about this problem?

If so, please include examples.


**Note:**

I'm not looking to process millions of numbers this way, just around 100 or so.

Comment: Do you want to convert array of strings to the array of integers? Or do you have this array like one string?

Comment: Right. I want to extract the numbers out of this string, and put them into a `uint8` array.

Answer (score 3):

Since the type returned is a `string`, the numbers are stored in a dynamic `bytes` array. This means that **each character occupies a single `byte` slot**. The ASCII/UTF-8 bit representation of numbers is linearly increasing, you can parse the numbers as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract NumParser {
    string[] public numArray;
    uint256[] public shouldBe;

    constructor() public {
        numArray.push("31");
        numArray.push("25");
        numArray.push("24");
        shouldBe.push(31);
        shouldBe.push(25);
        shouldBe.push(24);
        uint256[] memory result = parseNums(numArray);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            assert(result[i] == shouldBe[i]);
        }
    }

    function parseNums(string[] numsToParse) internal pure returns (uint256[]) {
        uint256[] memory parsed = new uint256[](numsToParse.length);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < numsToParse.length; i++) {
            bytes memory temp = bytes(numsToParse[i]);
            for (uint256 j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
                parsed[i] += (uint256(temp[j]) - 48) * (10**(temp.length - 1 - j));
            }
        }
        return parsed;
    }
}
```

The `constructor` contains a verification test that the function does indeed work correctly. **The function you want to use is the `parseNums` function**.

EDIT: You should change your original question to include that **you are receiving the array in `string` format**.

I have altered my function to work with your array as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract NumParser {
    string public numArray;
    uint256[] private tempContainer;
    uint256[] public shouldBe;

    constructor() public {
        numArray = "[\"31\", \"25\", \"24\"]";
        shouldBe.push(31);
        shouldBe.push(25);
        shouldBe.push(24);
        uint256[] memory result = parseNums(numArray);
        tempContainer.length = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            assert(result[i] == shouldBe[i]);
        }
    }

    function parseNums(string numsToParse) internal returns (uint256[]) {
        bytes memory converted = bytes(numsToParse);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) {
            if (converted[i] == 34) {
                tempContainer.push(0);
                uint256 j = i + 1;
                for (; converted[j] != 34; j++) {
                    tempContainer[tempContainer.length - 1] += (uint256(converted[j]) - 48);
                    tempContainer[tempContainer.length - 1] *= 10;
                }
                tempContainer[tempContainer.length - 1] /= 10;
                i = j;
            }
        }
        return tempContainer;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that processing a `string` like this is quite costly. You also **cannot use a `memory` array compared to the first solution** because `memory` arrays need to have a pre-declared size while you cannot find the amount of numbers you are going to get in your array from the raw string.

This also increases the gas cost so I would advise zeroing the length as shown within the `constructor` to reduce the cost.

Comment: This solves the problem of converting a string of numbers to uints. But my main problem here is taking the string `["31", "25", "24"]` and extracting the numbers out of there and putting them into a `uint8` array. So I guess what would need to be done to ignore the `[`, `]`, `"`, and `,` characters whilst still extracting the numbers and converting them to `uint8`s?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, you never specify that it is a `string` nor do you have it in escaped format i.e.: `"[\"31\", \"25\", \"24\"]"` I edited my answer according to your additional specifications.